# Angular.js deep object resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

This is a bit of a wide question, so I will endeavour to be succinct.

Whilst working on the import procedure of an application, I have run into the following data structure:

```
[
  {
    type: foreignParent,
    children: [
      {
        type: foreignChild
        imported: true|false
      },
      {
        type: foreignChild
        imported: true|false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The list of parents is provided by one API call, the list of children for that parent, provided by an additional API call for each parent (1+n), and the value of `imported` changes based on whether or not something exists in the `localChildren` object, of things already imported into the platform. `foreignParent`, `foreignChild` and `localChild` are three distinct objects with different structures provided by three distinct services.

The question then, is whether it is better to use the three services involved in this controller action to build one large array of objects, and simply iterate over it with `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in foreignParents">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="c in p.children">
        {{c.imported ? 'Imported' : 'Not Imported'}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In which case, I would have to setup watchers, to walk the hash, and re-calculate the values of imported if the list of objects in the `localChildren` service changes, additionally tracking the object

A second option would seem to be assigning a function to the `imported` and `children` properties, which I assume would then be calculated every digest cycle:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in foreignParents">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="c in p.children()">
        {{c.imported() ? 'Imported' : 'Not Imported'}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The rather simpler 3rd option would be to have a native object, with no function properties, and put the functions on the controller:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in foreignParents">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="getChildren(p)">
        {{isImported(c) ? 'Imported' : 'Not Imported'}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Presently the controller looks more or less like this:

```
app.controller('ImportCtrl', function ($scope, foreignParent, foreignChild, localChild) {

  $scope.foreignParents = [];

  $scope.githubRepositoryImported = function(repo) {
    localChild.RefNameExists(repo.ref_name);
  };

  foreignParent.Get().then(function(collection){
    _.each(collection.data, function(elem, i, list){
      foreignChild.Get(elem.login).then(function(collection){
        $scope.foreignParents[i].children = collection.data;
      });
    });
    $scope.foreignParents = collection.data;
  })

}]);
```

Which unfortunately does not work in the way I intended, but that's because of data problems on my side. I spoke with some friends about this, and nobody knows what the widely accepted **correct** way to do this would be, so I offered to post it to StackOverflow to get a second opinion.

***I'm simply not sure which is the correct methodology for these complex nested list, composed of more than one service, or how to see how many times the list is being digested, and how changes in function results might be propagated.*** I'm sure in some cases I might need an explicit `$scope.$watch` or possibly even to force a `$scope.$digest`, but until now I haven't found that I've had to dig into watches or digests. I have not found in the wild a complex enough example app to make a good comparison.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand is you may need to use [`$q.all()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#all) when cycling though the collection array and returning promises of singular items.

Try something like this

```
getCollection().then(function(collection){
  var arr =[];
  angular.forEach(collection,function (item){
    arr.push(getSingular(item.id));
  });
  return $q.all(arr);
}).then(function(t){
  // note this response will be an array of the returned promises.
  $scope.foreignParents = t;
});
```

I have taken the liberty of creating a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KGJGvo3ODKXpVPdk9MME?p=preview) for you.

I hopes this helps you.